# Data Guard Status: ORA-16764 after switch to log transport services

Tags: oracle

I originally set up our physical standby database with redo transport services. Now, I'm switching to log transport services to reduce the time in which the standby lags production. I set up a new log_archive_dest_n to use LGWR ASYNC, enabled it, and deferred the old log_archive_dest_n. Everything seems to work: Enterprise Manager Data Guard reports log transport services are being used, and the apply lag time is now around 20-30 seconds. I'm happy with that. What bugs me is that the primary database insists on reporting "ORA-16764: redo transport service to a standby database is offline". I realize it's offline; I took it offline because if it's online, Oracle insists on using redo transport instead of log transport. If I remove the dest_n parameter entirely, I get a Data Guard status of ORA-16777.

Is there a way to get rid of the error messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the issue is resolved. Oracle support recommended deleting and re-adding the standby from the data guard screen in Enterprise Manager. I did that, and at first the issue appeared resolved. Soon, however, a new error, ORA-16778 began to appear. After a bit of tail-chasing, I realized that the Data Guard process had re-added the log transport service to the initialization parameters, creating a duplicate of the one I had already added. Removing the entry that I had created and leaving the DG added one has the problem in remission.  Thanks for looking.